# c# : the type or namespace NativeWifi could not be found?

Tags: c#

In relation to this [C# - How do I access the WLAN signal strength and others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686715/c-how-do-i-access-the-wlan-signal-strength-and-others)

I tried finding .net and anc com .. in the add reference section , but no idea what is the reference that will help here . 
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) you simply need to include the two .cs files (Interop.cs and WlanApi.cs) to your project or first compile the ManagedWifi.csproj as separate assembly and then reference the resulting assembly to your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a codeplex project afaik, you can download the project from here: [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)