# Capture Geo location in WinForm desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, geolocation

I am working on windows form application in which I want to get the geo location of machine on which my application is installed.

How can I capture Geo location or **longitude and latitude**  of that machine?

What are the different way to **capture geolocation** (or **tracking location** of machine/device) in C#.net?

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716881/geolocation-in-winforms-application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211640/how-can-i-use-html5-geolocation-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: [System.Device.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location) .Net Framework only, a temp .Net Core port [here](https://github.com/dotMorten/System.Device) --> [Ask Geo](https://askgeo.com/) or similar Google APIs.