# API to check wireless connections

Tags: c#, api, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find a list of wireless networks (SSID's) in Java, C#, and/or C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c)

I want to display all currently available networks in my app. Similar to the wireless network configuration screen in Windows, I want to show which one is secured and which one is public.  Is there an API in C# I can use?

Comment: Native WIFI API Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not provide an API to access the wireless networking.
You should use [Native Wifi Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706275%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to access Wifi via P/Invoke.

For example, in order to get the list of available Wifi networks, use [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706749%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Just figured out that managedwifi [link](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) uses Native Wifi Reference [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706275%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), so there aren't many options to choose :)

Answer (score 0):

I've googled these ones:

- [managedwifi on codeplex](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)
- [related discussion on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/a2daf71e-b0f2-4d0d-bbf0-54518881cafd/)

Hope it'll help.