# Wlan SSID in java/c++

Tags: java, c++, windows, native, wifi

Is there any way i can get WLAN information f.e. SSID, Signal strength etc in java or C++?

I know about the wlanscan function in C++. Can anyone give me any example on how to implement it?

There is also a jwlanscan api for java but its not working for me.

OS: Windows 7

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
        {
            System.loadLibrary("wireless"); 
        }
        List list = getNetworkAdapterInfo();
        if (list == null)
            System.out.println("None Network Adapter.");
        else
            for (Iterator ite = list.iterator(); ite.hasNext(); )
            {
                NetworkAdapterInfo nic = (NetworkAdapterInfo)ite.next();
                System.out.println(nic.toString());
                List listap = getWirelessApInfo(nic.getName());
                if (listap == null) {
                    System.out.println("None Access Point.");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Access Point:");
                    for (Iterator ite1 = listap.iterator(); ite1.hasNext(); )
                    {
                        WirelessApInfo ap = (WirelessApInfo)ite1.next();
                        System.out.println(ap.toString());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

So far i have this code (jwlanscan api). It does not return any access point.

Comment: Check the following post it might be helpful:
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21092/WLAN-Scan-with-NDIS-Miniport-and-Much-More ??

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan: this is not java or C++. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, i got the answer myself. :)

[WLAN API for getting signal strenth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192376/wlan-api-for-getting-signal-strenth)

This C++ code displays all the required wlan information.

Answer (score 0):

following post details how to create WLAN object and access the info you need

[How to find a list of wireless networks (SSID's) in Java, C#, and/or C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c)

```
    WlanClient client = new WlanClient(); 
foreach ( WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces ) 
{ 
    // Lists all available networks 
    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList( 0 ); 
    foreach ( Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks ) 
    {                      
        Console.WriteLine( "Found network with SSID {0}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid)); 
    } 
} 

static string GetStringForSSID(Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid) 
{ 
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString( ssid.SSID, 0, (int) ssid.SSIDLength ); 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

OK, my bad,

I guess there is no native java api's for wlan connections. only way to do it is to go through OS native api and get the info.