# C# get network ssid in to a string

Tags: c#, ssid

Is it possible to make C# get the network SSID into a string?

I have not found anything like this and was wondering if it even is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-sharp-net-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-sharp-net-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c

Comment: all of those links are windows only :(