# Native Wifi won't show all available Networks

Tags: c#, networking, wifi

So I followed this example: [How to find a list of wireless networks (SSID's) C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917910/how-to-find-a-list-of-wireless-networks-ssids-in-java-c-and-or-c) and now have following code using Native Wifi (like the accepted answer of the link):

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
foreach ( WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces )
{
    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList( 0 );
    foreach ( Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks )
    {                     
        SomeListBox.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(network.SSID, 0, (int)network.SSIDLength))
    }
}
```

But this doesn't list all networks it only lists the one I'm currently connected to. Only if I press the Windows Wlan button in the taskbar, the code lists all networks. Did I do something wrong or is there a way to trigger this Windows Wlan scan thing?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so calling `wlanIface.Scan();` before `Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);` did the thing for me so that the full code now looks like this:

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
foreach ( WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces )
{
    wlanIface.Scan();
    Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
    foreach ( Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks )
    {                     
        SomeListBox.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(network.SSID, 0, (int)network.SSIDLength))
    }
}
```